# php pdo code to create rows dynamically from user input?

Tags: php, pdo

column name = receipts  (txtbox)

**if user enter receipts = 5 then insert 5 rows in database.**

**data insert in  table like this..**

receipts

1
2
3
4
5

**if user enter again receipts = 3 then again insert 3 rows in database.**

6
7
8

like wise....

**plz suggest me how to do this...**.

below is my code to save in php pdo...

i tried below code this is working but not inserting no in sequential order....

```
     if(isset($_POST['save']))
        {       
                        $book_no = $_POST['book_no'];
                       $receipt= $_POST['receipt'];
for($row=1;$row<=$receipts ;$row++)
{                                           
    $insertrow = $database->insertRow("INSERT INTO scheme_master (book_no,receipt,created) VALUES (:book_no,:receipt)", 
                        array(':book_no'=>$book_no,':receipt'=>$receipt)); 
}                           
        }
```

Comment: What rows you got into your db?

Comment: i need  when i enter 4 in receipt  txtbox then loop  insert 4 rows and value goes in  in sequence like 1234 etc in receipt column in database.....

Comment: now my code insert 4 rows but values not in sequence order......

Answer (score 1):

First you have to change the following code:

```
$insertrow = $database->insertRow("INSERT INTO scheme_master (book_no,receipt,created) VALUES (:book_no,:receipt)", 
                    array(':book_no'=>$book_no,':receipt'=>$receipt));
```

like this (the receipt number is the `$row` var, not the `$receipt` var)

```
$insertrow = $database->insertRow("INSERT INTO scheme_master (book_no,receipt,created) VALUES (:book_no,:receipt)", 
                    array(':book_no'=>$book_no,':receipt'=>$row));
```

If you want that, the next time, it start from the last number inserted (that is, for example, start from 6, if the previous time you have inserted 5 receipts), you have to query the DB to get the the current max value, and then start from it. To get the max, a query like this should work:

```
SELECT MAX(receipt) FROM scheme_master where book_no = :book_no
```

Comment: but plz suggest how to create for loop ........for inserting values in sequence in database.

Comment: @martinagrawal sorry for `$r`, it was `$row`. I've corrected the code above.